# SQL Query to select rows based on specific condition

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Below is an example of childs daily activity. I want to select the next rows after the last 'Play' activity based on user id.

```
id          timestamp               activity
567     1541300537817000            Play
567     1541300584959000            Games
567     1541300711884001            Play
567     1541300749548000            Study
567     1541300804865000            Movie
678     1542073550481000            Computer
678     1542073551422000            Play
678     1542073551478000            Play
678     1542073561885000            Play
678     1542073567663000            Sleep     
908     1543580126943000            Tv     
908     1543580212409000            Sleep     
908     1543580245227000            Play

Expected output

id          timestamp               activity
567     1541300749548000            Study
567     1541300804865000            Movie 
678     1542073567663000            Sleep
```

I tried doing this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM `table` t1, `table` t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
  AND t1.timestamp > t2.timestamp
  AND t2.activity = 'Play';
```

But it is giving me events after 1st Play activity.

Comment: how do i select last rows after play activity is what i am trying to figure out.. it would be a great help if u could help me with that

Comment: I know this is a similar problem, and u r the one who provided the solution.. but i am stuck with this problem.. any suggestions would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to solve by adding one more copy of a table for to check there is no 'Play' activity after.

But it's better to use a subquery for to select last 'Play' activity, and get all records after it:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `table` t1, (SELECT id, MAX(`timestamp`) `timestamp`
                  FROM `table`
                  WHERE activity = 'Play'
                  GROUP BY id) t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
  AND t1.`timestamp` > t2.`timestamp`
```

Comment: I think that is not correct.your query retrieves all rows of a user with a timestamp that is larger than the largest PLAY-timestamp and not only the next one. So for user  567 you will retrieve Study and Movie. That is wrong.

Comment: @miracle173 Author *want to select the next row**s** after the last 'Play'*. "Rows" may be "all rows" or "some rows", but can not be "only one row".

Comment: you re right, I see his expected output.

Answer (score 0):

1. GROUP the result by Id , finding the max date for each group where the activity is for a player
2. JOIN the result  FROM 1 to the original table ON each Id  and print the result for a grouped user having a date BIGGER than the one in the join.

Search how to do the first part without killing the performance. 
When doing the second part use It with appropriate indexes and probably with temp tables created with triggers or jobs. For example a job can update a lot smaller table with the results of task 1. every night.

Comment: *having a date BIGGER than the one in the join* whereas *finding the max date for each group*. Do you really await that there exists a record in a table with the date greater than maximal date in the same table?

Comment: Nice one - sorry. - amended

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data indicates that you want all activities after last `PLAY` per `ID`. One way is to ask for all activities where it does not exist a play at a later time:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t as t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM t as t2
    WHERE t2.activity = 'Play'
      AND t2.id = t1.id
      AND t2.timestamp > t1.timestamp
);
```